# PHP to change format of malformated timestamp to number of seconds

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp, date-format

I have a mysql table containing timestamps in the following format.

> April 23, 2011 at 10:00 PM

How would I use php to change the format of this oddly formated timestamp into the format you get when this is declared: `echo date('U');` aka seconds since the Unix Epoch. Then I would like to update my table with the new format.

Comment: It's stored as text. Yes, I know that's stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can `strtotime()` save it?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

If not, then you are going to need to explode on ' ' and ',' and then do some math to get into seconds

Comment: **WOW!** strtotime() did it! even with the " at " in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
echo date('U', strtotime(str_replace('at', '', 'April 23, 2011 at 10:00 PM')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even without php.
Add int_timestamp column to your table, update it with sql query:

```
update table set int_timestamp=unix_timestamp(str_to_date( odd_timestamp, '%M %d,%Y at %h:%i %p' ))
```

Ensure your newly created timestamps are correct (some timezone related problems are possible), drop old timestamp and rename your new one to old one.

Comment: This looks awesome, but would you please explain what each of the words stands for. example: "table" is supposed to be the name of my table. What do the other things like "int_timestamp", "unix_timestamp", "str_to_date", and "odd_timestamp" stand for?

Comment: int_timestamp is the name of column in your table that you need to create to hold your new timestamp as integer, odd_timestamp is the column holding timestamp you want to change, unix_timestamp() is the mysql function converting mysql datetime to php-like integer timestamp and str_to_date() is mysql function converting your odd formatted date into normalized mysql datetime format.